# Maintain two folders when building an application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following the below approach when building an application. I am using Angular,but this issue is not limited to Angular.
I have two folders, one called **build** and the other called **src**. `I am doing the development inside src but the application is run from build`. Gulp is responsible to populate build folder with the appropriate files (either replicated from src or created with Gulp; e.g. one .CSS file is creating in build from concatening many .SCSS files from src).

*My question is if this is a right approach. Is the use of build folder redundant?  Is there any best practice method for that?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best practice only.

Basically when the app contains a lot of JS and CSS files, you need to merge them into a common file in your build folder which will be ultimately deployed.

Since gulp merges all JS files to a single file and same for CSS, this makes the browser make only two requests (one for JS and one for CSS) which is good for performance as well. If a an SPA containing a lot of JS files, its not good for the browser to make individual requests to fetch each and every JS. Similar is the case for CSS as well.

**Build folder** : the one which will be deployed. It is made using GULP, GRUNT or any other task runner

**src**: Where you do development and ultimately merge all your CSS and JS to a single file for CSS and JS respectively included in build

Answer (score 0):

i think it's good practice build app from source code and put result to production, it's absolutely better than put source code to production. With your practice you put bundle, not project source with subfolders and subfiles